# Free space shows full space while adding ubuntu as a dual boot

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a lenovo G50-70 laptop with 500GB hard drive and 8 GB RAM(Existing 4GB removed and added a single 8 GB strip) with windows 10 installed in it. Now i am trying to dual boot for installing ubuntu. I have split my D drive to have 100GB unallocated drive. But when i boot with ubuntu CD it shows whole 500GB as free space, not able to see the 100GB unallocated space. I tried partitioning with both default disk management as well as minitool partition wizard.
[image: From Disk Management]

[image: From ubuntu installation]

Comment: Can you still boot into windows? Does the partition for windows exist?

Comment: I am able to boot into windows without any issues. yes, the partition for windows exist. When i noticed that the free space as full hard drive space i stopped installing ubuntu. Currently the machine has only windows.

Comment: Is ubuntu aware of the NTFS filesystem (ntfs-3g), also is ubuntu trying to use a GPT partitioning scheme or. a MBR scheme?

Comment: In windows while partitioning with minitool partition wizard it shows MBR scheme. Not sure about ubuntu, when i choose "something else" as an option while dual booting it shows free space with size as 500GB. Does that answer? or please let me know how to check

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot from either Windows Disk Management or from the specific installation step. It could help.

Comment: @Seth Added the screenshot